# How to add row with default values into System.Data.DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, system.data

I have `DataTable` and I need to add `row` with default values and save it into database.

BONUS: Would be awesome to auto increment key column.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Look at this doc from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx - but you should consider doing this at the database level (if youa re using a database) at least for auto-increment key.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int i = 1;
private void CreateDefault()
{
    DataColumn column = null;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    column = new DataColumn();
    var Col1 = column;
    Col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    Col1.DefaultValue = i;
    Col1.Unique = false;
    table.Columns.Add(column);
    i = i + 1;

    column = new DataColumn();
    var Col2 = column;
    Col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    Col2.DefaultValue = "Your String";
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    DataRow row = null;
    row = table.NewRow();

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Variable `i` will be auto increment key column. Now Insert the `DataTable` to `DataBase`.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a new row with default values and save it into database like this.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YourTableName", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter() { SelectCommand = cmd };

    // Load records to a DataSet
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "YourTableName");
    var table = ds.Tables["YourTableName"];

    // Add a new row with default value
    table.Rows.Add();

    // Reflect the change to database
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    da.Update(ds, "YourTableName");
}
```

Also, if you've set an auto increment key like IDENTITY for MS SQL Server (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx), this works when the new row is inserted.

Comment: Could you please show your connectionString(except password, etc...) and name all the columns with its default values? I'd like to figure out why this didn't work in your database.